Append to a line only if regexp is found
I have the following Ansible code:
---
- name: skip fail2ban in iptables checkmk plugin
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: modify plugin
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/plugins/mk_iptables
        backrefs: True
        regexp: '^(iptables-save.*)'
        line: '\1 | grep -v "f2b"'

What I want here is to append  | grep -v "f2b" to the line that starts by iptables-save in a bash script. This works fine.
However, I would like to make it so that if the grep function was already added, don't add it again. So I try some sort of ^(iptables-save.*)(?[grep]) which I had no luck with, probably because I misunderstand

how to correctly exclude a pattern within a regexp and
it seems like lineinfile will still append to EOF if no matches are found.

How can I get around this?

Q: "How to correctly exclude a pattern within a regexp?"
For a test file mk_iptables with content of
START
iptables-save foo bar
END

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: False
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

    - name: modify plugin
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: mk_iptables
        backrefs: True
        regexp: '^(iptables-save.*)(?<!"f2b")$'
        line: '\1 | grep -v "f2b"'
      diff: True

will result into an output of
TASK [modify plugin] *****************
--- before: mk_iptables (content)
+++ after: mk_iptables (content)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 START
-iptables-save foo bar
+iptables-save foo bar | grep -v "f2b"
 END

for the first run and for the second
TASK [modify plugin] *****************
ok: [localhost]

as well a test file content of
cat mk_iptables
START
iptables-save foo bar | grep -v "f2b"
END

Credits To

Regex for string not ending with given suffix

"You can also easily extend this with other characters, since this checking for the string and isn't a character class." (?<!string)$




Put the arguments into the blocks. It's easier to escape the special character(s)
    - replace:
        path: mk_iptables
        regexp: "{{ regexp }}"
        replace: "{{ replace }}"
      vars:
        regexp: |
          ^(iptables-save.*)(?<! \| grep -v "f2b")
        replace: |
          \1 | grep -v "f2b"

Given the file
shell> cat mk_iptables
START
iptables-save foo bar
END

the above task does what you want (--check --diff)
--- before: mk_iptables
+++ after: mk_iptables
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 START
-iptables-save foo bar
+iptables-save foo bar | grep -v "f2b"
 END

The above task is idempotent.


Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: mk_iptables
        regexp: "{{ regexp }}"
        replace: "{{ replace }}"
      vars:
        regexp: |
          ^(iptables-save.*)(?<! \| grep -v "f2b")
        replace: |
          \1 | grep -v "f2b"


